# How do I install a native dependency with a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I'm developing a Chrome extension that relies on a Python script in order to work. We contact with it via Native Messaging. We would like to have the Python script installed and the Registry Key created when the extension is installed. How should we go about doing that? Is it possible to do it from the `onInstalled` event?

Comment: Open a new tab page with an instruction and a button to download the installer script or exe which you can either package inside the extension or distribute from your site. I don't know though how web store reviewers would react to that but their process is mostly random anyway so it's worth a try.

Comment: With COVID19, it's important to mention that additional delays for web store reviews are expected, outside of the "normal" delays.